# Very slow login + very slow response - dbus error? - Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS - on Virtualbox 5.2.18 r124319 (Qt5.6.3) - on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Tags: linux, ubuntu, osx, virtualbox

This looks similar to dbus errors I see reported, but they are supposed to be fixed.

The system is extremely slow performance, particularly at logon - even the console logon is very slow.

There are errors like:

> dbus-daemon[1308]: [session uid=0 pid=1300] Activated service
>   'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1
>   exited with status 1

To try to get some understanding of this, I ran the systemctl status command suggested in some reports:

> $sudo systemctl status -l dbus-org.freedesktop.login1.service
>   * systemd-logind.service - Login Service    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service; static; vendor preset:
>   enabled)    Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-09-26 11:37:57
>   SAST; 30min ago
>        Docs: man:systemd-logind.service(8)
>              man:logind.conf(5)
>              https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind
>              https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat  Main PID: 667 (systemd-logind)    Status: "Processing requests..."
>       Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)    CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-logind.service
>              `-667 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
>
> Sep 26 11:51:21 govern systemd-logind[667]: Failed to start user slice
>   user-0.slice, ignoring: Connection timed out
>   (org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Timeout) Sep 26 11:51:46 govern
>   systemd-logind[667]: Failed to start user service, ignoring: Failed to
>   activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out
>   (service_start_timeout=25000ms) Sep 26 11:52:12 govern
>   systemd-logind[667]: Failed to start session scope session-11.scope:
>   Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out
>   (service_start_timeout=25000ms) Sep 26 11:52:37 govern
>   systemd-logind[667]: Failed to stop user service: Failed to activate
>   service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out
>   (service_start_timeout=25000ms) Sep 26 11:53:02 govern
>   systemd-logind[667]: Failed to stop user slice: Failed to activate
>   service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out
>   (service_start_timeout=25000ms) Sep 26 11:54:52 govern
>   systemd-logind[667]: Failed to start user slice user-0.slice,
>   ignoring: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed
>   out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
>   (org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut) Sep 26 11:55:17 govern
>   systemd-logind[667]: Failed to start user service, ignoring:
>   Connection timed out Sep 26 11:55:43 govern systemd-logind[667]:
>   Failed to start session scope session-9.scope: Connection timed out
>   Sep 26 11:56:08 govern systemd-logind[667]: Failed to stop user
>   service: Connection timed out Sep 26 11:56:08 govern
>   systemd-logind[667]: Failed to stop user slice: Failed to activate
>   service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out
>   (service_start_timeout=25000ms)

I'd be very grateful for any suggestions as to how to fix this..

Comment: Happened to me as well, on AWS environment. Saw this in /var/log/kern.log  
    Nov 17 09:47:22 in01-sliv kernel: [   78.375893] systemd[1]: segfault at 50 ip 000055a95e2af200 sp 00007ffe77ea4f60 error 4 in systemd[55a95e210000+14e000]`  
After that there are frequent errors like this:  
    [  188.290227] systemd-journald[419]: Failed to send WATCHDOG=1 notification message: Connection refused  
And anything systemd related timeouts..

Comment: It happens to me as well and it's over a year later; I don't use systemd. After starting dbus as a system-wide service all su or logins are really slow, take several minutes, then they fail. Running strace su - shows timeouts and failures, trying to communicate with dbus via sockets.